# Codechef: reverse Polish Notation

Tags: c, postfix-notation

This is the code for reverse polish notation. When I run it on unix it works fine but codechef says wrong answer. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void push(char);
void pop();

char stack[400];
unsigned long top=0;

int main()
{
    unsigned long len, test_case,i=0,j=0;
    char expr[400];

    scanf("%u\n",&test_case);

    for(;j<test_case;j++)
    {
        scanf("%s\n",expr);
        len=strlen(expr);

        for(;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(expr[i]=='+'||expr[i]=='-'||expr[i]=='*'||expr[i]=='/'||expr[i]=='^')
                push(expr[i]);

            else if(expr[i]==')')
            {
                pop();
            }

            else if(expr[i]=='(')
                continue;

            else
                printf("%c",expr[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void pop()
{
    if(top==-1)
        return;
    else
    {
        printf("%c",stack[top]);
        top=top-1; 
    }
}

void push(char x)
{
    if(top==400)
        return;
    else
    {
        stack[++top]=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the problem, but shouldn't the i variable be reset to zero during each iteration of j?

Comment: 1. Can you think of *any* RPN input that would *not* work with this? 2. Account for **all** possibilities from #1. 3. Have you stepped through *multiple* RPN samples with this? 3. When posting questions about CodeChef or other such programming task websites, *link the specific site question.*

Comment: `char expr[400];` I think 400 is the maximal length of the input. You need space for the 0-terminator.

Comment: do you assume the output and what kind of input?
Show a specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
 for(;i<len;i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
```

and then it will work fine. In codechef there are many testcases, so in your program it will work fine for 1st testcase but it will fail after that because the value of 'i' from the 2nd testcase will start from where it ends in the 1st case. So,you have to initialize the value of i in every testcase.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same situation and this is my solution to that problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char stack[400];
unsigned long top = 0;

void pop() {
    if (top == -1) {
        return;
    } else {
        printf("%c",stack[top]);
        top = top - 1;
    }
}

void push(char x) {
    if (top == 400) {
        return;
    } else {
        stack[++top] = x;
    }
}

int main() {

    unsigned long t, n, i = 0, j = 0;
    char a[400];
    scanf("%lu", &t);

    while(t--) {
        scanf("%s", &a);
        n = strlen(a);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] == '+' || a[i] == '-' || a[i] == '*' || a[i] == '/' || a[i] == '^') {
                push(a[i]);
            } else if (a[i] == ')') {
                pop();
            } else if (a[i] == '(') {
                continue;
            } else {
                printf("%c", a[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You missed writing some sections and there is another notation along with +, -, * and / i.e. ^ which was also required for the evaluation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only place that I noticed for the time being

```
`scanf("%u\n",&test_case);` //"%u" for unsigned not unsigned long

`scanf("%s\n",expr);` //%s : newline to not input are separated by white space
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize unsigned long i = 0 ; inside for loop as if you take two or more test cases i will initiate from where it left in last case for every next case .

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
top=0;
stack[0]=0;
```

**before ending `for` loop** in function `main` and change
`for(;i<len;i++)` to `for(i=0;i<len;i++)`.